# Alfresco sdk 3 : populate fields after selection

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I would like to populate fields after selecting item :

step1 (ok) :
[image]

step 2: 
[image]

and step 3 (what i try to do...) :

[image]

i can isolate info in Json Result but i don't know how to place it in the right field.
example username must populate "identifiant" field :
[image]

Comment: your question is not fully clear.Please describe it more.

Comment: means he wanted to populate other fields based on selection right  @anakin59490 ?

Comment: Exactly ! I want to poulate other fields when i select patient.

Comment: you have all form field ids so you can update the value of other form field based on selection.

Comment: use custom ftl in that you will set all required field values

Comment: i dont know how to retrieve the value "username" . for the moment i use "document.getElementById('page_x002e_data-form_x002e_task-edit_x0023_default_assoc_wfvd_patients-cntrl-picker-selectedItems').outerText;" with split() function in order to get values